# How can i customize "Completed the [Product Name] Setup wizard" in wix ui dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, wix

Need to change "Completed the [Product Name] Setup wizard" message to "[Product Name] installed successfully." in wix ui dialog?

Comment: you could follow [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462452/3046223) to the similar question, because the solution is actually the same, just use [ExitDialog.wxs](https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset/blob/master/RC0-source/wix36-sources/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/ExitDialog.wxs) instead of FatalError. I cant write the full answer at the moment, sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing text in the standard Wix dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723840/customizing-text-in-the-standard-wix-dialogs)

Comment: Actually there is another way to solve your problem. You can use localisation as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1725018/3046223)