# Wix Installer - Customize MsiRMFilesInUse dialog box

Tags: wix, wix3.11

I was trying to change the default MsiRMFilesInUse dialog box provided by restart manager used in wix toolset. Basically I want to localize the default message in the dialog box since it is not getting localized by windows.

[image]

I found this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/46462452/14162315) which explains the steps of making the custom dialog box instead of normal one. A custom dialog box could help me in localizing the message.

I tried the above steps but I am getting the error - `Duplicate symbol 'Property:WixUIRMOption' found. This typically means that an Id is duplicated. Check to make sure all your identifiers of a given type (File, Component, Feature) are unique.`

I thought that I have to change the property id of WixUIRMOption also to some custom value to mitigate the error, so I changed it to Custom_WixUIRMOption. It compiled successfully after this change but the dialog box is not coming at all after this change.

link to source code of default MsiRMFilesInUse.wxs - https://github.com/AnalogJ/Wix3.6Toolset/blob/master/RC0-source/wix36-sources/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/MsiRMFilesInUse.wxs

Answer (score 1):

you should be fine if you provide a localization for MsiRMFilesInUseText.

```
<String Id="MsiRMFilesInUseText" Overridable="yes">Translated text</String>
```

See how the dialog is implemented:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/MsiRMFilesInUse.wxs

See how wix ui is translated:
https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/UIExtension/wixlib/WixUI_en-us.wxl